# String indexOf issues in UTF

Tags: android, string, indexof

I am trying to highlight string in string if the first one contains the second. The problem is that when the parent string contains accented characters, `indexOf` returns me the index of the first match with an error. **filterText** is the String to highlight. For example.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_search, parent, false);
            // configure view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.tvName.setTypeface(tfBold);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setTypeface(tfRegular);

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(getSpannedFromHtml(parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle()));
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(getSpannedFromHtml(parkingList.get(position).getPostSubTitle()));

        if(getUTF8Length(filterText) > 2){
            if(parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterText)) {

                Log.d("AAA", "length 1: " + parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).length());
                Log.d("AAA", "length 2: " + getUTF8Length(parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).toString()));


                // Find all occurrences for the fist letter of filterText in Name
                for (int cont = -1; (cont = parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US), cont + 1)) != -1; ) {
                    String str1 = "";
                    String str2 = "";
                    String str3 = "";

                    Log.d("AAA", "parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US)): " + parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US)));

                    Log.d("AAA", "parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US): " + parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US)));

                    if (cont > 0)
                        str1 = viewHolder.tvName.getText().subSequence(0, cont).toString();
                    str2 = viewHolder.tvName.getText().subSequence(cont, cont + getUTF8Length(filterText)).toString();
                    if ((cont + getUTF8Length(filterText)) < getUTF8Length(viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString()))
                        str3 = viewHolder.tvName.getText().subSequence(cont + getUTF8Length(filterText), getUTF8Length(viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString())).toString();

                    String highlilightedString = str1 + "<font color = #ef6c00>" + str2 + "</font>" + str3;
                    viewHolder.tvName.setText(getSpannedFromHtml(highlilightedString));
                }
            }

            if(parkingList.get(position).getPostSubTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterText))
                // Find all occurrences for the fist letter of filterText in Description
                for(int cont = -1; (cont = parkingList.get(position).getPostSubTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US), cont + 1)) != -1;){
                    String str1="";
                    String str2="";
                    String str3="";

                    if(cont > 0)
                        str1 = viewHolder.tvDescription.getText().subSequence(0, cont).toString();
                    str2 = viewHolder.tvDescription.getText().subSequence(cont, cont + filterText.length()).toString();
                    if((cont + filterText.length()) < viewHolder.tvDescription.getText().length() )
                        str3 = viewHolder.tvDescription.getText().subSequence(cont + filterText.length(), viewHolder.tvDescription.getText().length()).toString();

                    String highlilightedString = str1 + "<font color = #ef6c00>" + str2 + "</font>" + str3;
                    viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(getSpannedFromHtml(highlilightedString));
                }
            }

        return rowView;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private int getUTF8Length (String str) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int cont = 0, len = str.length(); cont < len; cont++){
            char ch = str.charAt(cont);
            if(ch <= 0x7F){
                count++;
            } else if(ch <= 0x7FF){
                cont+=2;
            } else if(Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)){
                count+=4;
                cont++;
            } else {
                count+=3;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

The problem is that if parkingList (position) contains for example the string "Pokémon Shop" and filterText contains "mon", indexOf method returns 9 instead of 4. The following logs are of the example if the chain evaluated is "Pokémon Shop" and the string to search inside is "mon":

```
D/AAA: length 1: 17
D/AAA: length 2: 17
D/AAA: parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US), 0): 9
D/AAA: parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US): 9
```

Comment: have you log this expressions ? 
pstr.toLowerCase(Locale.US)  and filterText.toLowerCase(Locale.US) ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373213/java-ignore-accents-when-comparing-strings

Comment: I can see 4. http://ideone.com/UIYoci

Comment: it may be a character encoding issue. For a quick test, please try removing the `é` char

Comment: by the way, what does `pstr` refer to?

Comment: what is `pstr`?  (see `pstr.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(....`)

Comment: added the real code. sorry

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947992/java-unicode-string-length

Comment: for the sake of debugging, alongside their length you could print each string, and each code point of each character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of your **getUTF8Length()**. It gives you the wrong length value. Try the code below. (You may have to adjust the regex to meet your string requirements.)

```
private int getUTF8Length (String str) {
    int count = 0;

    List<String> characters=new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\\s*\\p{L}*]\\p{M}*");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        characters.add(matcher.group());
    }

    count = characters.size();
    String s = characters.toString();
    Log.d("LogDebug", s);

    return count;
}
```

Sample output:

```
D/LogDebug: [P, o, k, é, m, o, n,  , S, h, o, p]
D/LogDebug: getUTF8Length() = 12
```

PS. This code is based on [Java Unicode String length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947992/java-unicode-string-length) with regex adjusted to string input "Pokémon Shop".