# Traverse Telugu words letter by letter in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, apache-poi, utf-16

String string = "రాజులకు రాజైన యీ మన విభుని పూజ సేయుటకు రండి"; //28

I need to traverse these letters one at a time without breaking.

for me it is coming as , because I am splitting using charAt function traversing through the string.
ర     ర       ా       జ       ు       ల       క       ు               ర       ా       జ       ై       న               య       ీ               మ       న               వ       ి       భ       ు       న       ి               ప       ూ       జ               స       ే       య       ు       ట       క       ు               ర       ం       డ       ి

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use `string.codePoints()`/`string.codePointAt()`.

Comment: `BreakIterator` is the general way to iterate over junks of strings in various Unicode-specified units. Which one exactly you need I can't say (I don't know Telugu and don't know your precise requirements).

Comment: @AndyTurner how to use codePoints please.. it returns 43 for that length of string when there are only 28 characters ..how to interpret this please.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949292/2985643) to the question [Java Unicode String length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15947992/2985643) provides Java code which uses a regex to extract each letter from a String. It was written for processing Tamil, but it works fine for your Telugu string as well. I just ran it, and it extracted 21 Telugu letters `రా, జు, ల, కు, రా, జై, న, యీ, మ, న, వి, భు, ని, పూ, జ, సే, యు, ట, కు, రం, డి` (plus 7 spaces = 28, which is what you expect).

Comment: For instance the first _Telugu "letter"_ `రా` (user-perceived) is  `ర` (U+0C30,  *Telugu Letter Ra*) plus - `ా` (U+0C3E,  *Telugu Vowel Sign Aa*) i.e. _two_ codepoints `\u0C30\u0C3E`. Read more at [UNICODE TEXT SEGMENTATION](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Comment: @skomisa This works and I see it in console.. but when I put the same in word, the rendering is lost somehow.. could you help?`List<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>();
   Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}\\p{M}*");
   Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(arr[i]);
   while (matcher.find()) {
    characters.add(matcher.group());
   }

   for (Iterator iterator = characters.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String charat = (String) iterator.next();
    tableRowBlank.addNewTableCell().setText(" ");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("  "+charat+"  ");
         }`

Answer (score 0):

> [This accepted answer by halex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949292/4299358) to the question [Java Unicode String length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15947992/4299358) provides Java code which uses a regex to extract each letter from a String:
>
> > ```java
> > String s = "ஈஉஐ రాజైన";  // Tamil/Telugu text input
> > List<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>();
> > Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\u0B95\u0BCD\u0BB7\\p{M}?|\\p{L}\\p{M}?");
> > Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(s);
> > while (matcher.find()) {
> >   characters.add(matcher.group());
> > }
> >
> > System.out.println(characters);
> > System.out.println(characters.size());  // Length
> > ```
>
> It was written for processing Tamil, but it works fine for your Telugu string as well. I just ran it, and it extracted 21 Telugu letters రా, జు, ల, కు, రా, జై, న, యీ, మ, న, వి, భు, ని, పూ, జ, సే, యు, ట, కు, రం, డి (plus 7 spaces = 28, which is what you expect).

([skomisa's comment to the question, 2022-02-16 15:31:00Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143472/traverse-telugu-words-letter-by-letter-in-java#comment125761664_71143472)) This solves it.

Comment: [1] You should post the code you ran in your answer, with your own explanation. As it stands your answer is not very helpful to future readers. [2] Since your code was primarily from an answer to another question, it is **very important** that you also include a link to it, and credit the original author. [3] To also extract spaces from the Telugu string, just change the regex passed into `Pattern.compile()` to `"\\x20|\\p{L}\\p{M}*"`, where `x20` is the space character, and `|` (vertical bar) is the OR operator. But there are many ways to do this, and there may be better approaches.